# Best way to structure addional tools/panels in cakePHP app?

Tags: php, cakephp

in our team we started to migrate an very old PHP-newbie project to cakePHP and I'd like you to ask about how to structure some parts of it:

We have:

- The cakePHP coreSources seperated in a vendors-directory
- The application (app)

So now the question is how to structure addional parts of the application which are seperated due to permissions. But they are related to the application and in the old version much sourcecode is duplicated which we want to avoid.

- admin tools panel
- payment panel
- support panel (lets say kind of help desk)

I'd like to keep them in seperated GIT repositories (as they are written by us and not 3rd party/vendors) and I dont want one huge repo which keeps the application and all of its addional panels.

So the question is: How to build this in cakePHP to avoid duplicate sourcecode? Example: A message written in the app should be visible in the suport panel when its reported as spam or bad words. (Do you understand what I mean?)

Shall we use plugins for the several panels or shall we build completly own cake-apps which will lead again to duplicate sourcecode? Are there other ways to deal with this problem?

Greetz

P.S. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right you want to have modules that can be shared between applications. [Plugins](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html) are the right choice then. You can manage them in git repos but I would use composer to install them in your apps.

Just putting something in a plugin won't make everything 100% reuseable and extendible make sure you write your code in a way that it can be extended using OOP principles and design patterns on app level if needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer right now.I edited first post and added a note that the admin panels etc. are not 3rd party, but developed by ourself. Thats because they are in a GIT repo. For external sources like cakePHP core code we are planing to use composer as you suggested here.